# Is the comparison of well-orders theorem true for classes?

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

The [classical *comparison of well-orders* theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010432/initial-segments-of-well-ordered-sets-are-isomorphic) states that for every two wosets ([well-ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)), one woset is an initial segment of the other one. I am wondering whether it is possible to use a similar theorem for the isomorphism of $\mathbf{ON}\cong \mathbf{ON} \times \mathbf{ON}$.

Is the following also true?

> **Theorem.** Let $\langle X,< \rangle $ and $\langle Y, \prec \rangle $ be two well-ordered classes; that is, $<$ and $\prec$ are two transitive, assymetric, linear, well-founded class relations. Then there exists an initial segment $\langle C, <\rangle $ of $\langle X,< \rangle $ that is isomorphic to $\langle Y, \prec \rangle $, or vice versa.

*Attempt of proof.* Denote $X_{<x} = \{ y\in X \mid y< x \}$. In an analogous way to the classical proof, define
$$
F = \{ \langle x,y \rangle \mid X_{<x} \cong Y_{\prec y} \}.
$$

1. We claim that $F$ is a class function. If both $\langle x,y \rangle$ and $\langle x,y' \rangle$ are members of $F$, we have $Y_{\prec y} \cong Y_{\prec y'}$ and we can deduce that $y=y'$.
2. Now prove that $F$ is a homomorphism of orders. If $y=F(x)$, there exist an isomorphism $g: X_{<x} \to Y_{\prec y} $. So if $x' < x$ we have $y' = F(x') $ for some $y'\prec F(x)$, since $g\restriction X_{<x'}$ is an isomorphism from $X_{<x'}$ to $Y_{\prec y'}$. Rephrasing, if $x<x'$ than also $F(x) \prec F(x')$. This proves that $F$ is a homomorphism, and that $C=\operatorname{dom}(F)$ is an initial segment.
3. Since $\cong$ is a symmetric relation, everything we proved so far is also true regarding $F^{-1}$. In particular, $F$ is an invertible homomorphism (since $F^{-1}$ is a function) and $D=\operatorname{ran}(F)$ is an initial segment in $Y$, s.t. $C\cong D$.
4. Assume to the negation that both $C$ and $D$ are proper initial segments in $X$ and $Y$ correspondingly. So we can write $C = X_{<x}$ and $D = Y_{\prec y}$ for some $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. So, by definition of $F$, $\langle x,y\rangle \in F$, contradicting the definition of $C = \operatorname{dom}(F)$. $\square$

If this indeed proves the comparison theorem of class well-orders, is there also a uniqueness theorem stating the every proper well-ordered class is isomorphic to $\mathbf{ON}$?

Comment: It reminds me the Mostowski's collapsing lemma for your last question. It works for a well-founded setlike extensional relation on a class.

Comment: @Maman Indeed I did not use here any set-like properties of the relations. So it seems that there is something fishy here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof does not work in NBG. It does, however, go through in the stronger MK.

It is valid to discuss, for each $x \in X$, the well-ordered class $X_{< x}$. However, this class could be proper; a simple example can be found in the set $X = \mathbf{ON} \cup \{*\}$, where $*$ is some non-ordinal defined to be larger than all ordinals; then $X_{<*} = \mathbf{ON}$. Incidentally, this answers your other question; $X$ is a larger well-ordered set than $\mathbf{ON}$.

And it is valid to discuss the contention that $X_{< x} \cong X_{< y}$. However, doing so requires a quantification over classes. Therefore, one would not be able to conclude that the class $F$ exists from NBG’s class comprehension scheme, since this scheme only works with formulas that quantify only over sets. However, $F$ *can* be constructed from MK’s class comprehension scheme.

Comment: So, if the well-orders are set-like (every proper initial segment is a set) the proof does work, as $X_{<x} \cong Y_{\prec y}$ can be stated using a first-order quantification on sets?

Comment: @RoySht Yes, precisely. And the largest set-like well-order is $\mathbf{ON}$ which, up to isomorphism, is the only proper set-like well-ordered class.